# Reordering Fields Appended With jQuery

Tags: civicontribute

I have appended a field to honoree-name-email-section and it works great.  However it appends to the bottom of the fields. I would like to append a field an have it be shown at the top of the list.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of moving #mycustomfields ahead of a .core-class:

```
function Refresh() {
  cj(function ($) {
    'use strict';
      /* move my custom fields up where they belong */
      $('.core-class').prepend($('#mycustomfields'));
  });
}
```

Open up an inspector tool for your browser to find the # or the . you'd like to move around using JavaScript. In Firefox I like Firebug: http://getfirebug.com/

In the example above I'm moving an entire div with id=mycustomfields.

@Josh ended up using:
'cj('#editrow-custom_25').insertBefore('.editrow_prefix_id-section');'

Many ways to re-order change things up in jQuery!

Comment: Sorry I am very new at this. What name goes in #mycustomfields. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Josh - I've added a bit more detail in my answer!

Comment: Karin,  Thank you very much.  But I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  !(https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XPtgJEnqAoRlZ6TXpGaXZUVUU/view?usp=sharing)  The code I am using is `{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
 cj('#editrow-custom_24').appendTo('.honoree-name-email-section');
 cj('#editrow-custom_25').appendTo('.honoree-name-email-section');
function Refresh() {
  cj(function ($) {
    'use strict';
      /* move my custom fields up where they belong */
      $('.core-class').prepend($('#editrow-custom_25'));
  });
}
</script>
{/literal}`

Comment: I think perhaps you want prepend instead of appendTo? See also: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_prepend.asp

Comment: Karin,  I appreciate all your help.  When I change appendTo to prepend the field no longer  shows up in the correct profile at all.  The code looks like `cj('#editrow-custom_25').prepend('.honoree-name-email-section');` Thanks!

Comment: As a sidenote, the new jQuery container for Civi is CRM.$ ?

Comment: I figured it out.  All with one line of code. 'cj('#editrow-custom_25').insertBefore('.editrow_prefix_id-section');'

Comment: Ah insertBefore - that's cool! Many ways to jQuery.